# How do I create a new Pandas column with a specific dtype?

Tags: python, pandas

For some reason, the dtype of  `due_date` is `object`. Based on the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), I can't tell if my input is incorrect or anything. The input variable `due_date` is a simple string of the form `8/1/20`.

Here are the relevant lines:

```
data_normalized.at[index, 'due_date'] = pd.to_datetime(due_date, format='%m/%d%Y', errors='ignore')
print(data_normalized['due_date'].dtype)
# output: object
```

Am I supposed to set the column type somewhere in the `at` function?

Comment: Can you add some example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you do a loop somewhere and update the cell with `at`. In doing so, you almost always have mixed type in your data. Instead, try doing something like:

```
data_normalized['due_date'] = pd.to_datetime(due_date, format='%m/%d%Y', errors='ignore')
```

Without your actual/full loop code, I'm not certain how you are going to update the whole series.

**Note** if looping is unavoidable, you can convert the whole series dtype after the loop

```
## looping
for index in data_normalized.index:
    data_normalized.at[index, 'due_date'] = pd.to_datetime(due_date, format='%m/%d%Y', errors='ignore')

## after loop
data_normalized['due_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_normalized['due_date'])
```